# How to fix error while install react-native-splash-screen

Tags: react-native

when I try to install this module using

> npm install react-native-splash-screen

I am getting this error

```
> 68 error code ENOENT 69 error syscall rename 70 error path
> D:\work\React native\Medigo\node_modules\react-native-splash-screen 71
> error dest D:\work\React
> native\Medigo\node_modules\.react-native-splash-screen.DELETE 72 error
> errno -4058 73 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
> 'D:\work\React native\project\node_modules\react-native-splash-screen'
> -> 'D:\work\React native\project\node_modules\.react-native-splash-screen.DELETE' 74
> error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. 75
> verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

how to fix this issue?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I fix it with file_get_contents();

Answer (score -2):

it is because you have running cmd with same directory.
if your app is running in other cmd, and you are trying to install new node module from other cmd, you get this error.
the solution is simple
just stop app and close all terminal and try again.
or clear all node modules and reinstall it.